# jQuery siblings method and set height

Tags: jquery, css, siblings

I have DOM structure like this

```
<div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="learnMore"><a class="learn-more" href="#path">Learn More</a>                     
</div>
<div>
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="description"></div>
   <div class="learnMore"><a class="learn-more" href="#path">Learn More</a>                       
</div>
```

On clicking the a tag I am trying to change the height of div with class description with in the same parent div

```
$('.learn-more').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.description').animate({height: '90px'}, 200);
}
```

This is failing all the time.

```
$('.description').animate({height: '90px'}, 200);
```

This works but it changes height for all the divs with that class name not just the one which is its sibling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no `.show-more` element in your HTML

Comment: have you tried `.next()` instead of `.siblings()`?

Comment: You also aren't closing your `.learnMore` div's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first solution, did you mean to use `.learn-more` instead of `.show-more`?
In that case, notice that the description div is not sibling of the link a tag; it's sibling of its parent. Add a `.parent()` call should fix this. I.e.

```
    $('.show-more').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.description').animate({height: '90px'}, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Yes. That was typo in my previous post. I have updated the selector in jquery to match the DOM.

And, thanks for pointing out the parent. That fixed the issue I had.